# iOS FTP concurrent upload and download

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, ios6

I am trying to write a code in which i have to create 2 parallel threads (Which is running inside a dispatch serial queue) 1 thread will upload and another thread will download the file from the server. Both of the upload and download progress is going to be updated on another screen with bytes upload and downloaded.

But I am facing some strange issues:-

1. As soon as I create secondary threads my functions returns to the dispatch Serial Queues and it starts another serial task scehduled instead of waiting for 2 current parallel Tasks to complete first.
2. As soon as the Download Threads starts the upload Thread Stops uploading file and returns -1 during Writeto server.

I am using Apple [SimpleFTP](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) example and trying to run it in 2 parallel threads 1 is for put and second for get.

Any Idea why the Upload stops while downloading file from server(I have made 2 different connnections to FTP server as well)

Advance Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't just using standard blocks with GCD + a `dispatch_semaphore_t` variable?

Comment: There are few other tasks happens in the serial queue (completes 1 after another) and those tasks should complete serially.. those serial queues are created with GCD itself. and for this FTP task we have to create 2 parallel threads and both upload and download should run concurrently.. I tried using GCD async with global dispath but instead of waiting for the task to be finished the original main serial queue start running the another task.. This is the requirement..

Comment: More update on this.. It seems like that the - (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode is blocking another thread from accessing the same delegate function in another class until the NSStream close is not get called. Can anyone throw some more light on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue using the Syncronous FTP request. The run loop run function was blocking the other thread from calling the stream delegate function.